# Запрос возвращает повторяющиеся значения

Tags: база-данных, oracle, запрос

есть запрос:

```
SELECT  name_department,  salary
FROM  listdep, (SELECT DISTINCT salary FROM listworker ORDER BY salary DESC)
WHERE ROWNUM < 6;
```

Вывод:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как исправить, чтобы он не возвращал повторяющиеся значения ?

Comment: Примерно так: `SELECT DISTINCT salary FROM listworker`

Comment: А что вы хотите добится этим запросом? В таком виде, как в вопросе он создаёт картезиан продукт из двух таблиц и значения конечно же будут повторятся.